# Expected value of number of different cards

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have this question:

> From a deck of $10$ cards, Tom draws two cards and places them back in the deck. Now Jerry draws two cards from the deck.
>
> Let $X$ be the number of cards that was chosen by only one of Tom or Jerry. What is $\Bbb E[X]$ ?

I've figured that the range of $ X$ is $\{0,2,4\}$, and calculated the probability for zero to be: $\frac 2{10} \frac 19$, as he needs to pick the same two cards.
The probability of two cards to be : $\frac 1 {10}$$\frac 89$ , as he needs to pick the same card once and a different card after.
The probability of $4$ cards : $\frac 8{10}$$\frac 79$, as he needs to pick two different cards.
$$\Bbb E[X]=4\frac 8{10}\frac 79+2\frac 1{10}\frac 89=\frac {8}{3}$$

But I have a mistake and I can't figure out what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: I haven't done the whole problem yet but surely $X$ can be zero if they each take the exact same pair.

Comment: I dont understand what this mean: "Let $X$ be the number of cards that was chosen by only one of Tom or Jerry." Can you explain it?

Comment: @T_M, yes you're right I forgot to add zero, but it won't affect the outcome.

Comment: @Masacroso , meaning that X represents the number of cards that was chosen by only one of them and not the other. i.e. Tom draws 1 and 2, if Jerry draws 3 and 4 than X equals 4 as in four different cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of picking two cards should be multiplied by $4$, because there are two cards to match with, and we can either match-miss or miss-match.

This gives the numbers of hands as $\{X=0:2, X=2: 32, X=4:56\}$

and gives the revised expectation as:

$$\Bbb E[X]=4\frac 8{10}\frac 79+2\frac 4{10}\frac 89=\frac {16}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach.

Number the cards from $1$ to $10$, and let
$$X_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 \qquad \text{if card i is chosen by exactly one of Tom and Jerry} \\
0 \qquad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
for $i = 1,2,3,\dots,10$. Then
$$P(X_i=1) = 2 \cdot \frac{2}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{10} = \frac{8}{25}$$
so the expected number of cards chosen by exactly one person is
$$E \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} E(X_i) = 10 \cdot \frac{8}{25} = \frac{16}{5}$$
where we have used linearity of expectation.

Comment: Is this a Bernoulli random variable approach?

Comment: @shahaf137 I suppose the $X_i$ are  Bernoulli variables, because they are $0$ or $1$, but they are not independent as in the Binomial distribution.  The usual terminology is "indicator variable". The nice thing about the theorem that $E(X+Y) = E(X)+E(Y)$ (linearity of expectation) is that it does not require that $X$ and $Y$ be independent, which is good for us in this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation !